# Use JQuery To Add Row To Table On Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, webforms

I am using the below C# to generate a table.  I need a way of adding in a button (on it's own row at the end of the html table) that when pressed will add a new row of textboxes.

How is this achieved in JQuery/JavaScript?

```
protected void btnGreen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);
    sb.Append("<table>");
    sb.Append("<tr>");
    sb.Append("<th>Spl</th>");
    foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem item in cbxTest.Items)
    {

        if (item.Selected) { sb.Append("<th>" + columnname + "</th>"); }
    }
    sb.Append("</tr>"); 
    int z = 2;
    sb.Append("<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"field1\"></td>");
    foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem item in cbxTest.Items)
    {
        if(item.Selected) { sb.Append("<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"field " + z + "\"></td>"); }
        z = z + 1;
    }   
    sb.Append("</tr>");
    sb.Append("</table>");
    other.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: It's a bit odd to make the row on the server and then amend it on the client. I'd suggest doing the whole task in one place - wherever you want that to be.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - my situation deems for one row to be added initially, but to allow the user to add rows as needed.  Would you recommend letting the html button click event fire in the C# then?

Comment: Personally I'd do it all client side to save the user having to wait for postbacks. You can load the first row, then `clone()` it when needed to create the other rows.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - would the syntax be <script>
$(function() {
  $("#add").on("click",function() {
  $( "td" ).clone();
 })
 });
</script>

Comment: Almost, `$('td:first').clone()` (or `:last`). Otherwise you'll copy all existing rows.

Comment: Button press does not add anything

Comment: You need to `append()` the cloned element back to the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest this

```js
protected void btnGreen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);
    sb.Append("<table id=\"tab\">");
    sb.Append("<thead>");
    sb.Append("<tr>");
    sb.Append("<th>Spl</th>");
    foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem item in cbxTest.Items)
    {

        if (item.Selected) { sb.Append("<th>" + columnname + "</th>"); }
    }
    sb.Append("</tr>"); 
    sb.Append("</thead>");
    sb.Append("<tbody>");
    sb.Append("<tr>");

    int z = 2;
    sb.Append("<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"field1\"></td>");
    foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem item in cbxTest.Items)
    {
        if(item.Selected) { sb.Append("<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"field " + z + "\"></td>"); }
        z = z + 1;
    }   
    sb.Append("</tr>");
    sb.Append("</tbody>");
    sb.Append("<tfoot>");
    sb.Append("<tr><td><button id=\"add\" type=\"button\">Add</button></td></tr>");
    sb.Append("</tfoot>");
    sb.Append("</table>");
    other.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $("#add").on("click",function() {
    var $row = $("#tab tbody tr").first().clone();
    $row.find("input").val(""); // here you can also change names if needed
    $("#tab tbody").append($row);
  });
});
```

Example:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#add").on("click", function() {
    var $row = $("#tab tbody tr").first().clone();
    $row.find("input").val(""); // here you can also change names if needed
    $("#tab tbody").append($row);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tab">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Spl</th>
      <th>columnname1</th>
      <th>columnname2</th>
      <th>columnname3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="field1"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="field 2"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="field 3"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="field 4"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td><button id="add" type="button">Add</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: In my instance - this duplicates the entire table - header and all.  Not just adding in a row below the current row?

Comment: I missed a `<tr>` Please see updated answer with example

Comment: There are two opening <thead> and only one close...  Altho, it does work with the update :)

Comment: @user2932408 ok - you get what you pay for. I do JS not .NET

Comment: No worries - I really really appreciate the help